# Openshift python manage.py test doesn't run

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, unit-testing, openshift, django-1.8

I followed 7 part tutorial in django documentation.
Django project was created with Openshift quickstart

Why do i need to type

```
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
```

before every unit test case execution

```
    python manage.py test
```

Whenever I add test case to my application and push all changes to openshift i need to retype migrations using SSH connection to openshift
before i can run tests
otherwise i see "no such table myapp_question" error message.

Using python manage.py dbshell i see that database is up with appropriate tables, since i already made all migrations.

The documentation states that ,
[Separate, blank databases are created for the tests.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)
Why openshift requires to type migrate before test ,without any model change and what happens to new database.

I instantiate every test case from

```
    from django.test import TestCase
```

and this import should provide out of the box required new database with empty table.

Should i put something in openshift hooks or modify settings.py.

I can run tests but i don't understand why i can't just type

```
      manage.py test
```

and explore results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every push to openshift using git creates new run-time without django database migrations and schema. All history of database is kept in [DATA](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#directory-variables) sub directory that can be accessed using ssh.

django tests require migrations history to recreate database for testing purposes,that uses memory database.

Only by running migrations and migrate schema for test is created.

Please, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: If you are using a file system database such as SQLite and not sticking it in the designated persistent data directory, then yes, you will need to create it each time. There is an environment variable you can use which gives location of directory.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to mention that i was using SQLite dabase ,because cartridge takes a lot of processing time to build it up. Thank you for clarification. There was feeling that i have been doing something wrong